# How to use Meteor packages outside of Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to use Meteor packages (like minimongo) outside the main Meteor app. Furthermore, I would like to connect to the MongoDB database of running Meteor app. So that I can have a background worker and similar things which should read/write to the app database. I would like to use minimongo to be really compatible with Meteor (like having same IDs). And I would like to be able to connect to app database also in development.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like a cron job? Or something you would need to run manually?

Comment: Also. But I had more in mind a constant background process which would do some heavier computation based on data in the database.

Comment: Ahh I see. You could also use a method/cron helper and if you were to run your intensive task in a new fiber it wouldn't block the user threads so performance wouldn't be impacted.

Comment: Do fibers use multiple cores? What is a method/cron helper?

Comment: a cron helper is like a timeout that runs whenever you set it (e.g with Meteor.setInterval). the method is a simple Meteor.methods() on the server which you can call when you want the task done. I know where you're coming from with your other question & feature request on meteorite so methods might be best since it has all the collections/code ready. The thing about node/fibers working on multiple cores is a bit confusing so im not sure on its multicore abilities. On its own node can't do it, but with fibers im not 100% sure

Comment: Is it video processing which is the chunky one? You could find all the stuff about what you want to do with the method and then run a wrapper that runs the executable with all the variables required that does this stuff externally so it takes advantage of multiple cores. With npm it should be possible