# How to use Meteor packages in non-Meteor project

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have standard node.js REST API. And I want to use some meteor's packages like Minimongo, Tracker, Blaze (any Meteor's package)

There a lot of articles how use npm modules in Meteor but I have opposite task. Should I create some wrapper to make it possible to use as a Node modules?

There is similar question: [How to use Meteor packages outside of Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859586/how-to-use-meteor-packages-outside-of-meteor) 
but nobody answer.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. Packages rely on the Meteor build tool, platform and other Meteor packages in order to build correctly. Some attempts were made to extract a subset of Meteor, [like this one](https://github.com/deanius/mini-meteor) or individual npm packages, but they don't seem to be active.

Comment: Hmmm looks interesting! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get the same issue so i look around perhaps it's too late 
However o found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-client-packages-meteor

*Perhaps it could be helpful now*

Or use this which the author recommends https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-webpack-client

Both are available..

Comment: Hi David! After 1 month I just give up ... And remove all code related to meteor, it's just piss me off. 
So I just believe that you've suggested is correct, and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

this is a good question, but you cannot just use `require` for a meteor in npm. You also cannot use Drupal modules in in plain PHP, it will not work as in the context they are written for. Yes you can use npm packages in Meteor, but only because Meteor is build on top of Node, not vice-versa.

Meteor has its own packaging system, because Meteor Packages are Isomorph, they have the ability to share their code on client and server, like the SimpleSchema Package or many others. To make it simple for developers to use it, it's an complete encapsulated system.

But to your question. There are a some of really valuable "ports" of Meteor Packages to plain npm architecture. For example you mentioned Tracker, so there is a npm package for that.

- Tracker:
  https://github.com/eface2face/meteor-tracker
  (There is no Readme, but I guess it should be used, like Meteor Tracker, right?)
- Minimongo:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimongo-standalone

... just to mention some...

To port a package you just need to extract the needed code, which don't depend on Meteor and other meteor packages and create a npm package of them.. So the code still behaves the same.. Just look at the Tracker code

You have to decide, why do you need meteor packages for your node/express application? And maybe there are already some better solutions in the npm world itself. If you really depend on major meteor packages, then just use Meteor ;)

Comment: Agreed! It's easier to get node packages into Meteor than the other way 'round.

Comment: Meteor is tooooo havy for my REST API. I will hate myself if do this :)
I want to say that, I like Meteor, but it's just wrong to use it just because of some specific packages. Anyway thank a lot for answer.

Comment: @Dilan So, what exactly do you need from meteor for your API?

Comment: @webdeb I want nothing from Meteor in my API. That's the problem :)
BUT, I need to use some (not all) functionality from package build for Meteor.

Comment: @Dilan I am sure you can avoid Meteor complete, if you need a client for meteor <-> node take a look at ddp.js

Comment: @webdeb It make sense when you need functionality available by websocket. But I want to use it in requirement style. For example mongo's schema specified in [common] folder of this package.
Thank a lot for DDP.js link.

Comment: @Dilan, If I answered your question, please accept it :)

Comment: You answer to my question but it does not appropriate for me. Do you see difference between  source code access and access restricted by API (in my case web socket).
I need to have access to some function defined in [common] folder like Mongo's schema, etc but I can get it via ddp! Only if I change meteor package and make this functionality myself. But this is weird

Comment: @Dilan sorry, I don't understand your real problem.. what do you mean with "access restricted by API (in my case web socket)"? I have the feeling, that your question is somehow basic for node architecture. Have you tried to `require` what you need?

Comment: @Dilan websocket is available as it's own package for npm.. no need meteor

Comment: @webdeb ok, more details. There is Meteor's package: https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-core and I want to use mongodb's schema defined in common/schemas. How could I do this with websockets?

Comment: @Dilan this are not schemas for mongodb, but for simpleschema, another meteor package.. There is a npm package called simple schema too, but I don't know if the schema format is compatible.. You have to try it, maybe you the customize a bit.. but this is another thread..